# completely uninstall r linux

Tags: linux, r

I am trying to update my version of R on linux mint, however broken dependencies are stopping me doing this. after trying everything such as adding repos from Cran, sudo apt-get update, I still cannot install the latest version of R.

MY question is how to i completely remove R from my machine, so that I can restart. I have tried :

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base
```

however when I run R it still works:

```
laptop$ R

R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

and doesn;t seem to be removed at all.

I want a clean, fresh install, but I don't think I am removing R properly

Comment: Have you seen this in [R docs](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Uninstallation) you can uninstall R with `make uninstall`

Comment: @Pippin Isn't that only if you built R yourself though?

Comment: The R binary (well, front-end script) is part of the `r-base-core` package which contains the core R system. The package `r-base` just pulls other packages in.

Comment: dirk can you put this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The R binary (well, front-end script) is part of the `r-base-core` package which contains the core R system.

The package `r-base` is a so-called virtual package which exists to just pulls other packages in. Removing it does not remove any parts of the R system --- for which you need to remove `r-base-core`.

Comment: How do I remove r-base-core?

Comment: I am using Fedora 20 and type `sudo yum remove r-base-core`, but that returns `No Match for argument: r-base-core
No Packages marked for removal` .

Comment: @gaelgarcia You are missing the fact that we talking about Debian-based systems here.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove r-base-core`

Answer (score 19):

You might want to check on all currently installed R packages.

You can list all packages whose name starts with "r-" like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '$2 ~ /^r-/ { print $2 }'
```

To uninstall all of them, pipe the output to `xargs apt-get remove`:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '$2 ~ /^r-/ { print $2 }' | xargs apt-get remove --purge
```

Comment: The second code line will work only with `-y` option for the `apt-get` command: `dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '$2 ~ /^r-/ { print $2 }' | xargs apt-get remove --purge -y`

Comment: Almost worked - failed because many of the packages ask for "y" to confirm and that caused the sequence to fail. Darn. Was trying to set an alias to r like an old UNIX system I used in the 90s it reran the last command where you specify at least one of the last command characters and specify as many needed for r to know which command to run it was a great time saver. The ! command might have been what it was and I plan to alias r with ! and get what I was used to. -Oh see the commenter above mine explained this.

Answer (score 9):

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '$2 ~ /^r-/ { print $2 }' | sudo xargs apt-get remove --purge -y
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Note **sudo** addition to the previous suggestion by others.

Comment: This appeared to work, but R still works in console despite none of those packages existing.

Comment: @Kyouma You probably have still a locally compiled R which can't be found with the solution. You could download the respective tarball from CRAN, untar, configure then make uninstall to get rid of it. Be sure to also delete _all_ packages folders, otherwise there might be trouble. Save package-names as character vector in an .rds and use it in `install.packages(package-names)` later.

Answer (score 6):

At your Linux command line, try:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "^r\-"
```

This will list R packages installed on your system. You can then delete them by name.

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this proves useful.
In addition to running:
`sudo apt-get remove r-base`
`sudo apt-get remove r-base-core`
try also:
`sudo apt purge r-*`

Answer (score 1):

The following does the job especially if you want to update your R version.

`sudo apt-get remove r-base-core`