# How to completely uninstall R on Fedora 20?

Tags: r, fedora, uninstallation, fedora20

I am using Fedora 20 and type:

`sudo yum remove r-base-core`, but that returns:

`No Match for argument: r-base-core`

`No Packages marked for removal`

Is this how I'm supposed to try to unisntall R?

Comment: As I told you already [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336644/completely-uninstall-r-linux/20341739?noredirect=1#comment53344053_20341739), you are confusing a Debian/Ubuntu package name with something that does not exist (under that name) on your Fedora system.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can do it correctly on Fedora?

Comment: You may need to become a little more familiar with the `yum` tool.