# Global install of R-packages fails

Tags: r, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I am running cmd-line R (version 3.3.1) without any problem. Installing any package locally from either CRAN or GitHub (i.e. for the user running the session) is ok.

However, in order to install pagkages globally, I use:

```
$ sudo su -l -c "/usr/bin/R -e \"install.packages('package-name', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
/usr/bin/R: line 8: uname: command not found
```

Following an `R` session is started and:

```
> install.packages('package-name',repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

is correctly executed inside the `R` session.

Package components are correctly downloaded and after the last one has finished downloading, I get the 16 identical instances of:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 8: uname: command not found
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 143: exec: sh: not found
```

followed in the end by

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpqL1osU/downloaded_packages’
There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> 
> 
sh: 1: rm: not found
```

I tried this for `devtools`, `swirl`, ..., all packages I want to install for all users on the platform.

Installation from CRAN in a local library, i.e. for a given user, gives no trouble. Can anyone suggest how I should proceed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that `/usr/bin` is not in your `$PATH` when you use sudo (`$PATH` from `/etc/sudoers` is used by sudo, `etc/profile` is not loaded.).

One workaround is to use `su -` and then execute the installation (`etc/profile` should be loaded). Another solution might be to add `/usr/bin` to the `$PATH` in your sudo statement.

Comment: Thanks Aeck, however `/usr/bin` is in my `$PATH` env-variable in `/etc/sudoers` and running with `- ` instead of  `-l` produces the exact same faulty result...

Answer (score 0):

I just spent well over an hour trying to troubleshoot this issue so I'm going to cross-post a [solution from RStudio](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-installing-any-package/49189/10) that worked for me (This post is easier to find on Google).

I was having unrelated issues with `reticulate` so I tried to start with a *clean-slate*. After [completely removing RStudio/r-base-core from Ubuntu 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336644/completely-uninstall-r-linux), then reinstalling, I noticed the issue from above:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 8: uname: command not found
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 143: exec: sh: not found
```

### The problem

I had a `.Renviron` file sitting in my home directory from a previous installation. It had `GITHUB_PAT`, `GITHUB_USERNAME` and a `PATH` (to python). Once I removed this I was able to install packages again.