# Rcpp package in R not install ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, rcpp

please help me in this. I tried installing `Rcpp` using

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp
```

and from R-Studio and got the same error:

```
> install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘highlight’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/highlight_0.4.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 356443 bytes (348 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 348 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2372283 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘highlight’ ...
** package ‘highlight’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASBeautifier.cpp -o ASBeautifier.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASEnhancer.cpp -o ASEnhancer.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASFormatter.cpp -o ASFormatter.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASResource.cpp -o ASResource.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASStreamIterator.cpp -o ASStreamIterator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Matcher.cpp -o Matcher.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Pattern.cpp -o Pattern.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ansigenerator.cpp -o ansigenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c bbcodegenerator.cpp -o bbcodegenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c codegenerator.cpp -o codegenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c configurationreader.cpp -o configurationreader.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ctagsreader.cpp -o ctagsreader.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c datadir.cpp -o datadir.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c documentstyle.cpp -o documentstyle.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c elementstyle.cpp -o elementstyle.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c highlight_wrapper.cpp -o highlight_wrapper.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c htmlgenerator.cpp -o htmlgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c languagedefinition.cpp -o languagedefinition.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c latexgenerator.cpp -o latexgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c platform_fs.cpp -o platform_fs.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c preformatter.cpp -o preformatter.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c render.cpp -o render.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rtfgenerator.cpp -o rtfgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c stringtools.cpp -o stringtools.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c stylecolour.cpp -o stylecolour.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c svggenerator.cpp -o svggenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c texgenerator.cpp -o texgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xhtmlgenerator.cpp -o xhtmlgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xmlgenerator.cpp -o xmlgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xterm256generator.cpp -o xterm256generator.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o highlight.so ASBeautifier.o ASEnhancer.o ASFormatter.o ASResource.o ASStreamIterator.o Matcher.o Pattern.o ansigenerator.o bbcodegenerator.o codegenerator.o configurationreader.o ctagsreader.o datadir.o documentstyle.o elementstyle.o highlight_wrapper.o htmlgenerator.o languagedefinition.o latexgenerator.o platform_fs.o preformatter.o render.o rtfgenerator.o stringtools.o stylecolour.o svggenerator.o texgenerator.o xhtmlgenerator.o xmlgenerator.o xterm256generator.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight/libs/highlight.so':
  /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight/libs/highlight.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘highlight’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api.cpp -o api.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpsPMzSK/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘highlight’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/highlight_0.4.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 356443 bytes (348 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 348 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2372283 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘highlight’ ...
** package ‘highlight’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASBeautifier.cpp -o ASBeautifier.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASEnhancer.cpp -o ASEnhancer.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASFormatter.cpp -o ASFormatter.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASResource.cpp -o ASResource.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ASStreamIterator.cpp -o ASStreamIterator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Matcher.cpp -o Matcher.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Pattern.cpp -o Pattern.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ansigenerator.cpp -o ansigenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c bbcodegenerator.cpp -o bbcodegenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c codegenerator.cpp -o codegenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c configurationreader.cpp -o configurationreader.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ctagsreader.cpp -o ctagsreader.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c datadir.cpp -o datadir.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c documentstyle.cpp -o documentstyle.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c elementstyle.cpp -o elementstyle.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c highlight_wrapper.cpp -o highlight_wrapper.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c htmlgenerator.cpp -o htmlgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c languagedefinition.cpp -o languagedefinition.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c latexgenerator.cpp -o latexgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c platform_fs.cpp -o platform_fs.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c preformatter.cpp -o preformatter.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c render.cpp -o render.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rtfgenerator.cpp -o rtfgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c stringtools.cpp -o stringtools.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c stylecolour.cpp -o stylecolour.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c svggenerator.cpp -o svggenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c texgenerator.cpp -o texgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xhtmlgenerator.cpp -o xhtmlgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xmlgenerator.cpp -o xmlgenerator.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I. -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xterm256generator.cpp -o xterm256generator.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o highlight.so ASBeautifier.o ASEnhancer.o ASFormatter.o ASResource.o ASStreamIterator.o Matcher.o Pattern.o ansigenerator.o bbcodegenerator.o codegenerator.o configurationreader.o ctagsreader.o datadir.o documentstyle.o elementstyle.o highlight_wrapper.o htmlgenerator.o languagedefinition.o latexgenerator.o platform_fs.o preformatter.o render.o rtfgenerator.o stringtools.o stylecolour.o svggenerator.o texgenerator.o xhtmlgenerator.o xmlgenerator.o xterm256generator.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight/libs/highlight.so':
  /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight/libs/highlight.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/highlight’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘highlight’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api.cpp -o api.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpsPMzSK/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Did you install R using `sudo apt-get install r-base` or copy it from another machine? See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943764/r-error-in-dyn-loadfile-dllpath-dllpath) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40603539/3022126)

Comment: Yes, have installed with sudo apt-get install r-base and also reinstalled R after uninstalling as told in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336644/completely-uninstall-r-linux and even deleted the folders listed after .libs command in R. Few days earlier I did an update and ggplot installation crashed with same error on Rcpp but have reinstalled everything. Still the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

This version of Rcpp is *not* installed via `apt-get` as a binary, but rather from source: `/home/sukumar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so`.

The error message `undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE` suggests you have mismatched compilers -- and older and a newer C++ compiler.

I would recommend you delete this version (ie do `rm -r ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/`), and make sure you do not have another version installed.  Then installation from source should work just fine.

You generally have a choice of using the prebuilt versions available with Ubuntu 14.04.   Or you could upgrade Ubuntu to version 16.04, or even 16.10.  All versions should have working Rcpp versions -- and installation from source should also work just fine if you have working and consistent versions of the required tools (ie `g++`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried uninstalling and installing 6 times with different solutions found on google. And I do have one and working g++.  Lastly I installed R from source and  set path to this version for RStudio. Rcpp had an success exit on installation.

Comment: Please subscribe to r-sig-debian and post there -- this makes no sense.  Thousands of people have used the binaries without issues.

Comment: And needless to say, I use Ubuntu myself (but upgrade every six months, so currently using 16.10 on my main machines).  This stuff just works, so you are doing something unusual somewhere.