# cannot install R tseries, quadprog ,xts packages in Linux

Tags: r, linux, yum, install.packages

I am using R version 3.4.0

I'm trying to install tseries package on linux machine:

```
install.packages('https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/tseries_0.10-42.tar.gz',dependencies = TRUE,repos = NULL,type ="source")

It gives error:
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xts'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/xts'
ERROR: dependency 'xts' is not available for package 'TTR'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/TTR'
ERROR: dependencies 'xts', 'TTR' are not available for package 'quantmod'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/quantmod'
ERROR: dependencies 'quadprog', 'quantmod' are not available for package 'tseries'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/tseries'

1: In install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package 'quadprog' had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package 'xts' had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package 'TTR' had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package 'quantmod' had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package 'tseries' had non-zero exit status
```

Then I tried installing quadprog using:

```
install.packages('https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/quadprog_1.5-5.tar.gz',dependencies = TRUE,repos = NULL,type ="source")
```

It gives error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [quadprog.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'quadprog'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/quadprog'
```

Please help what should i do. I'm facing hard time in installing these packages.

I have installed R using :

sudo yum -y install R-core R-devel

I tried installing gfortran using :  `yum install gcc-gfortran`

It says :Package gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Just *read* the error message: `cannot find -lgfortran`.  So install a Fortran compiler, presumably `gfortran` of the same release as your `gcc` and `g++` binaries.

Comment: How to install it, please tell. I have gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)

Comment: Please check edits. I tried installing gfortran

Comment: So you have the Fortran compiler. You still need the Fortran `-dev` package providing the Fortran library you failed to link against.  I do not know what RedHat/CentOS call that -- under Debian it would be `libgfortran-6-dev` for `gcc-6` etc pp.

Comment: Please help me to find it for RedHat/CentOS. I couldnt find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the Fortran compiler (`gfortran`) and the GCC compiler driver (`gcc`) are out of sync: `gfortran` is version 4.4.7, `gcc` is version 4.7.2.  This means that they use different directories to store there files, and `gcc` is unable to locate the `libgfortran.so` symbolic link installed by the `gcc-gfortran` package.

The solution is to bring these two compilers to the same version.  This can be achieved by adjusting the `PATH` variable (based on other discussions, `gcc` is not referring to `/usr/bin/gcc` here), deinstalling the software collection that provides this `gcc` command (using `yum remove devtoolset-1.1-gcc`), or installing the Fortran component for the same software collection, using `yum install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran`.

My best guess is that your `devtoolset-1.1-gcc` package comes from this repository:

- https://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/6/x86_64/RPMS/

So you could use the `gfortran` package from there, too (and pick the `c++` package as well, to avoid a similar problem).

Comment: Let say I do not want to deinstall and use the PATH variable to fix this issue? How do i do it?

Comment: You need to find out where `devtoolset-1.1-gcc` came from and install  devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran from the same source.

Comment: `rpm -qi devtoolset-1.1-gcc` might tell you who build this package.

Comment: I think it's coming from yum -y install centos6.iuscommunity.org/… \ 
&& yum -y install python36u \ 
&& yum -y install python36u-devel \ 
&& yum -y install python36u-pip \ 
&& yum -y install python36u-tkinter.x86_64

Comment: Can you tell how do i install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran from the same source?

Comment: I don't see any `devtoolset-1.1-gcc` package in the `centos6.iuscommunity.org` default repository. Does `yum info devtoolset-1.1-gcc` show any installation source?

Comment: Let me check wait

Comment: check our chat, i have added the results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150067/discussion-between-ashag-and-florian-weimer).

Answer (score 2):

After spending quite some time with the same error, the only solution that worked for me was to re-install all R components.

For completness, what I did was to remove all R components with:
`dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '$2 ~ /^r-/ { print $2 }' | sudo xargs apt-get remove --purge -y` (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336644/completely-uninstall-r-linux))

and re-install R again:  `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`

Comment: This worked for me as well as of June 22 2022 on Ubuntu R version 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I also could not install quadprog on Ubuntu due to a compilation error.
Running `sudo apt install zlib1g-dev` and restarting R solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reinstalling R from source using:

```
make install rhome=/usr
```