# how to install Fortran -dev package using sudo yum install

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, centos, shared-libraries

I have installed (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5) already and jave also installed yum install gcc-gfortran . (Package gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64)

But I'm getting error like :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [quadprog.so] Error 1
```

Please help me in installing -lgfortran. It seems like I need to install "Fortran -dev package providing the Fortran library".  I do not know how to do that in RedHat/CentOS. Please help. I'm facing hard time in doing this.

I have tried installing libgfortran using:

```
yum install libgfortran
```

But it says:

Package libgfortran-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
(Running in an interactive session, skipping clean step.)

More Info:
I tried installing package quadprog for R and below are the logs:

```
install.packages('https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/quadprog_1.5-5.tar.gz',dependencies = TRUE,repos = NULL,type ="source")
Installing package into '/usr/lib64/R/library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/quadprog_1.5-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 33651 bytes (32 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 32 KB

* installing *source* package 'quadprog' ...
** package 'quadprog' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran -m64  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c aind.f -o aind.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran -m64 -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules -ffloat-store   -c -o solve.QP.compact.o solve.QP.compact.f
solve.QP.compact.f:254.3:

 72   if (nvl .EQ. 0) then                                              
   1
Warning: Label 72 at (1) defined but not used
solve.QP.compact.f:302.2:

 7       t1inf = .FALSE.                                                
  1
Warning: Label 7 at (1) defined but not used
solve.QP.compact.f: In function 'qpgen1':
solve.QP.compact.f:94: warning: 'it1' may be used uninitialized in this function
solve.QP.compact.f:98: warning: 't1' may be used uninitialized in this function
gfortran -m64 -fvisibility=hidden -fpic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules -ffloat-store   -c -o solve.QP.o solve.QP.f
solve.QP.f:245.3:

 72   if (nvl .EQ. 0) then                                              
   1
Warning: Label 72 at (1) defined but not used
solve.QP.f:293.2:

 7       t1inf = .FALSE.                                                
  1
Warning: Label 7 at (1) defined but not used
solve.QP.f: In function 'qpgen2':
solve.QP.f:85: warning: 'it1' may be used uninitialized in this function
solve.QP.f:89: warning: 't1' may be used uninitialized in this function
gfortran -m64  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c util.f -o util.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -o quadprog.so aind.o init.o solve.QP.compact.o solve.QP.o util.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lgfortran -lm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [quadprog.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'quadprog'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/quadprog'
Warning message:
In install.packages("https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/quadprog_1.5-5.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package '/tmp/Rtmpry5XTG/downloaded_packages/quadprog_1.5-5.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

Edits :

```
bash-4.1# rpm -ql libgfortran
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
```

Comment: `yum install libgfortran` should install it

Comment: I tried this just now : found on this link https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libgfortran-4.8.5-11.el7.i686.rpm.html . BUt its already installed. I'm still getting same error

Comment: Please suggest something

Comment: Share your compilation command, Have you specified `-L` flag to point to `libgfortran`

Comment: I did yum install libgfortran . This is what you are asking?

Comment: As rpm is installed already, you might not be passing the location to `libgfortran` in your compilation which can be done by `-L` flag

Comment: So what should i do exactly?

Comment: Which command throw the error. Share that full command of compilation

Comment: If you want you can look at this link, to get more description on my problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292188/cannot-install-r-tseries-quadprog-xts-packages-in-linux

Comment: Instead of sharing the requested info, You are talking something else, If this goes on, I will lose interest to help you. Good luck

Comment: @dlmeetei Check edits added requested info

Comment: Now, Can you do `rpm -ql libgfortran` and share the location for `libgfortran.so`. Let us see if we are passing correct location

Comment: check edits please, added location info

Comment: Does your system have the file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgfortran.so`?  What does `readlink -f /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgfortran.so` say?

Comment: It says : /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0

Comment: Did you install a second `gcc`? What does `type -a gcc` print? And `readlink -f /usr/bin/gcc`? I tried on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 system, and `gcc` finds `libgfortran.so` there, so this has to be something peculiar to your installation.

Comment: type -a gcc : gcc is /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc'

Comment: readlink -f /usr/bin/gcc :    /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: What do you think from my above comments? It seems like I have 2 gcc's right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following compile line was looking for `libgfortran` at `/usr/lib64/R/lib` but the library is not there. Hence, the linker error.

```
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -o quadprog.so aind.o init.o solve.QP.compact.o solve.QP.o util.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lgfortran -lm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

As we could not locate and modify the `makefile`. We created a symbolic link `/usr/lib64/R/lib/libgfortran.so` to `/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3` and rerun the installation steps and it resolves the linker error.

This is a work around that we follow which resolves the issue

Comment: I do not know how to edit this makefile. Please guide.

Comment: `/usr/lib64` is on the default linker search path for this distribution, so it will not make a difference.

Comment: @dlmeetei Someone suggested "So you have the Fortran compiler. You still need the Fortran -dev package providing the Fortran library you failed to link against. I do not know what RedHat/CentOS call that -- under Debian it would be libgfortran-6-dev for gcc-6 etc pp."  If this makes any sense to you then please help

Comment: Downvoter, please explain the reason for downvoting? So that I can change, His issue is not passing the proper location to `libgfortran`

Comment: @Ashag, share you makefile in your question so that we can point where to modify

Comment: Which make file you want out of this?

Comment: I am sorry I can not help, you don't know which makefile you are using

Comment: If you can tell where i can find which makefile you are interested in and how to find. I can tell you. I am new to all this. i started with R and ended up in this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150049/discussion-between-dlmeetei-and-ashag).

Comment: I don't know which is accurate answer. But I have upvoted your answer. Both solution's worked for me. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you want you can also post your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292188/cannot-install-r-tseries-quadprog-xts-packages-in-linux . I will upvote it. that's where the problem started.

Answer (score 1):

You showed us this:

```
# type -a gcc

 gcc is /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc 
 gcc is /usr/bin/gcc'
```

It means that you have installed Red Hat Developer Toolset and enabled it for this shell, using `scl enable` or a similar command.  Do you still need it?  If not, I suggest to disable it.

If you need DTS, you will have to install the Fortran compiler from DTS 1.1, using:

```
yum install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran
```

(Or download it directly from [here](https://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/6/x86_64/RPMS/), which seems to be the repository from where you got your DTS compiler.)

This will install the Fortran compiler which is compatible with the gcc compiler you have configured. Without that, the system Fortran compiler and the DTS gcc are used together, which does not work because the DTS `gcc` command (used for linking in the build process you quoted) is not able to locate the `libgfortran.so` library from the system Fortran compiler.

Alternatively, you can bring the two compilers into sync by deinstalling the DTS compiler:

```
yum install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran
```

Comment: I don't think I need this. May be while trying to fix this, i have installed it. I will disable it. So what is the solution exactly?

Comment: Disable DTS, or install `devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran`. Either approach should fix your problem.

Comment: alright. I'm doing this. Will add a comment ; to let you know if it works or not

Comment: Please answer this; before doing yum install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran ; i need to disable something? If yes how do i disable? or else i should do yum install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran directly?

Comment: You can install the package directly.

Comment: Ok so when i did this ; it gave me this : No package devtoolset-1.1-gcc-gfortran available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Then you should try to disable DTS instead. Depending on how you have set it up, just logging in again may be enough to do this.

Comment: how to disable? I didnot do enable anytime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150052/discussion-between-florian-weimer-and-ashag).

Comment: I don't know which is accurate answer. But I have upvoted your answer. Both solution's worked for me. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you want you can also post your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292188/cannot-install-r-tseries-quadprog-xts-packages-in-linux . I will upvote it. that's where the problem started.