# Error while installing R package in AMI

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using my R studio via an EC2 instance in AWS.

I tried to install package =tidyverse in R stduio. but while installation i am getting an error

> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tidyverse’
>   had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/RtmpcH9Dy9/downloaded_packages’

Could anyone tell me how I could figure this out? Any lead would be helpful

EDIT: Console output

```
>     install.packages("tidyverse")
>     Installing package into ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
>     (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>     also installing the dependencies ‘mnormt’, ‘psych’, ‘broom’, ‘haven’, ‘modelr’, ‘readr’
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mnormt_1.5-5.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 37169 bytes (36 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 36 KB
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/psych_1.7.8.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3311758 bytes (3.2 MB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 3.2 MB
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.4.3.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1397648 bytes (1.3 MB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 1.3 MB
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/haven_1.1.1.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 189925 bytes (185 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 185 KB
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.1.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 83629 bytes (81 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 81 KB
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/readr_1.1.1.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 233793 bytes (228 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 228 KB
>     
>     trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61647 bytes (60 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 60 KB
>     
>     * installing *source* package ‘mnormt’ ...
>     ** package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>     gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c biv-nt.f -o biv-nt.o
>     f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
>     biv-nt.f:371:11:
>     
>            hs = sign( one, dh - r*dk )
>                1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     biv-nt.f:372:11:
>     
>            ks = sign( one, dk - r*dh )
>                1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c sadmvnt.f -o sadmvnt.o
>     f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
>     sadmvnt.f:976:3:
>     
>       10      END DO
>        1
>     Warning: Label 10 at (1) defined but not used
>     sadmvnt.f:80:15:
>     
>            INFORM = MVNNIT( N, CORREL, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, INFIS, D, E )
>                    1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:217:38:
>     
>              IF ( MINCLS .LT. 0 ) SBRGNS = WORK(LENWRK)
>                                           1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:275:21:
>     
>                  RGNCLS = RGNCLS*(MESH(DIVAXN)+1)/MESH(DIVAXN)
>                          1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:276:21:
>     
>                  NWRGNS = NWRGNS*(MESH(DIVAXN)+1)/MESH(DIVAXN)
>                          1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:1274:24:
>     
>                     POINTS = PONTRS(SUBTMP)
>                             1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:1275:24:
>     
>                     POINTP = PONTRS(SUBTMP+1)
>                             1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:1283:21:
>     
>                  POINTS = PONTRS(SUBTMP)
>                          1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:1303:21:
>     
>                  POINTS = PONTRS(SUBTMP)
>                          1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:324:15:
>     
>               TOP = PONTRS(1)
>                    1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:331:21:
>     
>                  RGNCLS = RGNCLS*MESH(I)
>                          1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:336:18:
>     
>               RGNCLS = RGNCLS*(MESH(DIVAXN)+1)/MESH(DIVAXN)
>                       1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:1585:3:
>     
>       10      END DO
>        1
>     Warning: Label 10 at (1) defined but not used
>     sadmvnt.f:1432:15:
>     
>            INFORM = MVTNIT( N, NU, CORREL, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, INFIS, D, E )
>                    1
>     Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
>     sadmvnt.f:1661:0:
>     
>           &              /( 1 + BMIN**2/(NU+I-1) )**( (NU+I-2)/TWO )
>      
>     Warning: ‘bmin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>     sadmvnt.f:1658:0:
>     
>           &              /( 1 + AMIN**2/(NU+I-1) )**( (NU+I-2)/TWO )
>      
>     Warning: ‘amin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>     sadmvnt.f:1127:0:
>     
>            INTEGER S, IXCHNG, LXCHNG, I, L
>      
>     Warning: ‘lxchng’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>     sadmvnt.f:804:0:
>     
>            END
>      
>     Warning: ‘__result_bvn’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>     sadmvnt.f:762:0:
>     
>            DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION BVN ( LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, CORREL )
>      
>     note: ‘__result_bvn’ was declared here
>     sadmvnt.f:1046:0:
>     
>                        IF ( INFI(I) .EQ. 2 ) Y(I) = ( AMIN + BMIN )/2
>      
>     Warning: ‘bmin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>     sadmvnt.f:1046:0: Warning: ‘amin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>     gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o mnormt.so biv-nt.o sadmvnt.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
>     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
>     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
>     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>     make: *** [mnormt.so] Error 1
>     ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/mnormt’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status
>     * installing *source* package ‘readr’ ...
>     ** package ‘readr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>     g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Collector.cpp -o Collector.o
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28:0,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:355:33:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          explicit shared_count( std::auto_ptr<Y> & r ): pi_( new sp_counted_impl_p<Y>( r.get() ) )
>                                      ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:256:65:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>      template< class T, class R > struct sp_enable_if_auto_ptr< std::auto_ptr< T >, R >
>                                                                      ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:471:31:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          explicit shared_ptr( std::auto_ptr<Y> & r ): px(r.get()), pn()
>                                    ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:484:22:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          shared_ptr( std::auto_ptr<Y> && r ): px(r.get()), pn()
>                           ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:567:34:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          shared_ptr & operator=( std::auto_ptr<Y> & r )
>                                       ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:576:34:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          shared_ptr & operator=( std::auto_ptr<Y> && r )
>                                       ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
>                      from Collector.h:5,
>                      from Collector.cpp:4:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:
> In member function ‘boost::shared_ptr<T>&
> boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(std::auto_ptr<_Up>&&)’:
>     /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:578:38:
> warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>              this_type( static_cast< std::auto_ptr<Y> && >( r ) ).swap( *this );
>                                           ^~~~~~~~
>     In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:61,
>                      from /home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
>                      from Collector.cpp:1:
>     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
>        template<typename> class auto_ptr;
>                                 ^~~~~~~~
>     virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
>     make: *** [Collector.o] Error 1
>     ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘readr’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/readr’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for package ‘psych’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/psych’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency ‘readr’ is not available for package ‘haven’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/haven’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘haven’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency ‘psych’ is not available for package ‘broom’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/broom’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency ‘broom’ is not available for package ‘modelr’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/modelr’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘haven’, ‘modelr’, ‘readr’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
>     * removing ‘/home/deepthi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
>     
>     The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/tmp/RtmpcH9Dy9/downloaded_packages’
```

> 

Comment: All that error tells you is that the installation failed for some reason. Have you been able to install other packages on this instance? Do you have proper permissions for your chosen package library? If the package was compiled from source, did the compiler give any errors? It might help if you provided the entire console ouput

Comment: @divibisan I have added the complete console output in the edit

Comment: It definitely looks like a compiler problem: ``` ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’``` but unfortunately this is beyond my expertise.

Comment: @divibisan thank you.. anyways

Comment: It seems you are missing some libraries required for compilation. You can see all the warning show the missing lib.

Comment: @mootmoot could you tel me what exactly i should do now

Comment: Always check the warning when you encounter any compiler error e.g. `f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ ` 
Here is a possible solution.  But I suggest also look around for question about tidyverse installation issues. Sometime it is just a simple libraries installation.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293476/how-to-install-fortran-dev-package-using-sudo-yum-install